# What is the bitfield permission flag for the "Manage Permissions" channel permission overwrite option?

Tags: discord, discord.js

When updating the permission overwrites of a channel in the Discord client you can see this option:

[image: Image of the Discord client's channel permission overwrites screen with option "Manage Permissions"]

If you manually enable the permission "Manage Channel" on a role, members with the role are able to edit the channel overview (like the name, topic, NSFW status, slowmode, etc.) but not the permission overwrites of it. Only enabling the  "Manage Permissions" permission lets that happen.

However, I have not found a permission bitfield flag to change this overwrite option anywhere in the Discord API. Neither the [Discord API Types website](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-payloads/common#PermissionFlagsBits) nor the [Discord Developer Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#permissions-bitwise-permission-flags) have any documentation of this option.

Using discord.js I tried updating a channel's permission overwrites with flag "ManagePermissions" like this:

```js
const channelOverwrite = guildChannel.permissionOverwrites.cache.get("id here");
channelOverwrite.edit({
    ManagePermissions: true
});
```

But I received a `RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: ManagePermissions.`

Does anyone know how to update this channel overwrite option using discord.js, or the Discord API at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, this option is really just the `ManageRoles` permission, but for a channel overwrite, and the Discord client just words it differently so it makes more sense in the context of a channel.

It can be edited like this:

```js
const channelOverwrite = guildChannel.permissionOverwrites.cache.get("id here");
channelOverwrite.edit({
    ManageRoles: true
});
```